# How would you implement a javascript function so that it has a notion of how many times it has been called?

Tags: javascript

```
console.log(foo()()); //it has to print '2'
console.log(foo()()()); //it has to print '3'
console.log(foo()()()()); //it has to print '4'
```

How would you implement `function foo(){}` to achieve the latter behaviour?

Here are my attempts to solve this:

```
foo.i = 0;
function foo(){
  foo.i++;
  return foo;
}

var f = foo()()()();
console.log(f.i); //prints 4
```

But of course

```
var f = foo()()()();
console.log(f.i); //prints 4
```

is NOT equal to

```
console.log(foo()()()());
```

Comment: how would **you** implement this functionality?

Comment: Are you asking a question about how to represent "static" variables or recursion?

Comment: I'm not even sure how to approach this.

Comment: why did you need this ??

Comment: What do you expect foo to return? a function or a number? What's wrong with `console.log(foo()()()().i);`

Comment: That's the problem, the function has to somehow know when to return a function and when to return a value to be printed O.o

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an inner function which increments the counter and implement a `toString` method for getting the count.

[`toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toString#Description) is called, if the expected value is a primitive type.

```js
function foo() {
    function x() { count++; return x; }

    var count = 1;
    x.toString = function () { return count; }
    return x;
}

console.log(foo());       // 1
console.log(foo()());     // 2
console.log(foo()()());   // 3
console.log(foo()()()()); // 4
```

Comment: Amazing Nina! Thank you very much.